# How to load a view in a particular region dynamically in Prism

Tags: prism, silverlight-5.0

In Prism Silverlight5, I have a shell which is divided into two vertical regions(leftRegion,rightRegion) & there are 2 views in Module1 i.e. (View1,View2).
 In leftRegion I have a View1 loaded which has a button.
 I want to dynamically load View2 on rightRegion using ViewModel & MEF.ViewModel code is :

```
    [Export(typeof(LeftViewViewModel))]
public class LeftViewViewModel:ViewModelBase,IViewModel
{
    [Import]
    public IRegionManager CullingRegion { get; set; }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LeftViewViewModel(LeftView view)
        :base(view)
    {
        LoadCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoadControl,CanLoadControl);
    }

    private void LoadControl()
    {
        CullingRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("RightRegion", typeof(RightView));
    }

    protected bool CanLoadControl()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public DelegateCommand LoadCommand { get; set; }
}
```

LeftView.xaml.cs is :

```
    [Import]
    public ViewModels.IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (IViewModel) DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
```

IModule implementation is :

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(CullingModuleModule1))]
public class CullingModuleModule1:IModule
{
    [Import]
    public IRegionManager CullingRegion { get; set; }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        CullingRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("ShellContentRegion", typeof (Container));
        CullingRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("LeftRegion", typeof(LeftView));


    }
}
```

Comment: A very general question, but please take a look at the following [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159887/Prism-for-Silverlight-MEF-in-Easy-Samples-Part-3-C); maybe it can help you along the way.

Comment: @Anders Loading View on right is working fine, but when I use MVVM with MEF along with it things are getting worst. It's just the button_click code been moved to ViewModel but it's not letting me load even the application.

Comment: what are you getting as error message ?

Comment: @HichemC I am not able to load even my left side view & getting error "error happened while creating region", is there anyway I can upload the full code to view?

Comment: Yes,you can publish suspected code using `{}` button in the editor

Comment: What should I pass from Initialize of IModule implementation View or ViewModel : CullingRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("LeftRegion", typeof(View1ViewModel)); I have reference of IView in IViewModel & reference of IViewModel in IView

Comment: This [Post](http://archfirst.org/books/getting-started-prism-and-mef) should help you structure your idea

Answer (score 0):

First of,I think your ViewModel should not be referenced by a View.
You may need to review View Injection with MEF.
As I've seen in multiple posts :

```
        [Export]
        public class YourViewClassName : UserControl
        {
            public YourViewClassName()
            {
            }
            [Import]
            public ILeftViewModel 
            {
                get { return (ILeftViewModel )DataContext; }
                set { DataContext = value; }
            }
        }

        [Export(typeof(LeftViewViewModel))]
        public class LeftViewViewModel : ILeftViewModel //ILeftViewModel inherits from IViewModel
        {
            public LeftViewViewModel()
            {
            }
        }
```

Inside Module Initializer :

`CullingRegion.Regions[YourRegionName].Add(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<YourViewClassName>());`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @HichemC. When you say "ViewModel should not be referenced by a View" that means I can use the code you mentioned below but not direct concrete classes? '[Import]
            public ILeftViewModel'. Also in your code implementation is the ILeftViewModel a markup interface or there is something inside it.

Comment: @Deepak ..Your first question : yes, Loose coupling principal always deemed good practice this is no longer PRISM but Design principal. That would make you code better testable too. Your seconde question : ILeftViewModel has nothing inside, this interface is somehow the address to the right class to import via MEF,each View or ViewModel should better implement its own interface.